# Different set.seed each run in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

I want to ***"measure"*** which Regression Method is more robust to the outliers.

For this, I sum the variances of model coefficients. Each run, I generate data from t-distribution. I set.seed Ten times to have Ten specific data.

However, I ***also*** want to have Ten different seed each run. So, in total, I will have 10 sums of the variances. The code below is giving me **one** sum of the first (Ten different seed).

How can I do this?

```
#######################################
p <- 5
n <- 50
#######################################
FX <- function(seed, data) {
#for loops over a seed #
for (i in seed) {
set.seed(seed)  
# generating data from t-distribution #
x<- matrix(rt(n*p,1), ncol = p)
y<-rt(n,1)
dat=cbind(x,y)
data<-as.data.frame(dat)
# performing a regression model on the data #
lm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data=data)
lm.coefs <- coef(lm1)
            
lad1 <- lad(y ~ ., data=data, method="BR")
lad.coefs <- coef(lad1)
          }
# calculate variance of the coefficients # 
return(`attr<-`(cbind(lmm=var(lm.coefs), lad=var(lad.coefs)), "seed", seed))
}
#######################################
seeds <- 1:10  ## 10 set seed to have diffrent data set from t-distribution #
res <- lapply(seeds, FX, data=data) # 10 diffrent variance of 10 data/model
sov <- t(sapply(res, colSums)) # put them in matrix
colSums(sov) # sum of 10 varainnces for each model.
```

Comment: The error is here: `for (i in seed)` only 1 value of the seed is being passed to the function on each call, thus your for loop is only running 1 time.

Comment: @Dave2e, What I need is to use let say (50) different (10) seeds. For example at first run seeds_1=1:10, the second seeds_2=11:21,... the seeds_50=100:120.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something closer to your intended results.
The code below fixes a key issues from your original code.  It was not clear on what data was intended to be returned from the function.

1. This creates a vector of seeds numbers inside the function
2. This also creates a vector to inside the function to store the value of the variance of coefficients for each iteration of the loop. (not sure if is what you want).
3. I needed to comment out the `lad` function since I do not know which package this is from. (you would need to follow 2 from above to add this back in.
4. Some general clean of the code

   ```
   p <- 5
   n <- 50


   FX <- function(seed, data) {
       #for loops over a seed #
     #Fixes the starting seed issue
     startingSeed <- (seed-1)*10 +1
     seeds <- seq( startingSeed, startingSeed+9)

     #create vector to store results from loop iteration
     lm.coefs <- vector(mode="numeric", length=10)
     index <- 1

     for (i in seeds) {
       set.seed(i)  
       # generating data from t-distribution #
       x<- matrix(rt(n*p,1), ncol = p)
       y<-rt(n,1)
       data<-data.frame(x, y)
       # performing a regression model on the data #
       lm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data=data)
       lm.coefs[index] <- var(coef(lm1))

       #   lad1 <- lad(y ~ ., data=data, method="BR")
       #   lad.coefs <- coef(lad1)
       index <- index +1
     }
    # calculate variance of the coefficients # 
    return(`attr<-`(cbind(lmm=lm.coefs), "seed", seed))
   }


   seeds <- 1:10  ## 10 set seed to have diffrent data set from t-distribution #
   res <- lapply(seeds, FX, data=data) # 10 diffrent variance of 10 data/model
   sov <- t(sapply(res, colSums)) # put them in matrix
   colSums(sov) # sum of 10 varainnces for each model.
   ```

Hope this provides the answer or at least guidance to solve your problem.

Comment: many thanks. I would like to make sure. Your code now will calculate 10 variances and store them and they will be added together. This process will be repeated 10 times. So, we will have 10 sums. For lad the package is "L1pack"

Comment: Could you please clarify these startingSeed <- (seed-1)*10 +1
  seeds <- seq( startingSeed, startingSeed+10), and index <- 1,  index <- index +1.

Comment: This is just generating a list of seeds `(seed-1)*10 +1` for seed =1 the output is 1 for 2, it's 11 to  etc. Then the `seq` function take the input and generates 10 consecutive  seed values. 1, to 10, 11 to 20, etc.  `index` is exactly that, an index to store each of the 10 iterations of the  `for` loop into a vector (in this case "lm.coefs")

Comment: Thank you so much. same process if I add lad?

Comment: Why the results do not change when for example I set seeds=1:100?

Comment: The number of results stored in "res" should match the number of seeds from the line above.  If you are referring to the numerical values, that won't change since the initial random number seeds is constant as defined in the function.

Comment: Kindly, check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119617/generate-cluster-outliers-in-r