# Generate specific outliers with random data in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to produce a cluster outliers as in the figure below to investigate that situation in more depths.

I tried but with nothing, because the figure has one dependent and independent variable. I **want** the same situation **but** with more than one independent variables. **So**, it will be **one** dependent variable and a **matrix** of independent variables.

[image]

My attempt R-Code was as below

```
n=50
p=2
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p),ncol = p)
y <- rnorm(n)
b=quantile(x,probs = 0.95)
id=which(x>b)
no=length(id)
x[id]=rnorm(no,5,0.5)
y[id]=rnorm(1)+10
```

**UPDATE**

I try the following code but still is not the same as shown in the figure

```
xa=rnorm(50)
xb=runif(50,min = 0,max=400)
x=rbind(xa,xb)
y=rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I kinda don't understand your question. On one side, you are talking about "matrix of independent variables". So, more than one. On the other side, you insist on "the same plot as shown in the figure". Yet, the figure shows only one independent variable. So, what do you want, actually? **It will not be possible to answer the question unless you make clear what you want. Bounty will not help you when question is unclear.**

Comment: @TMS, simply, what I need is y vs x[,1], y vs x[,2], ...., y vs x[,10]. If you plot all of this one by one it will give as the figure above. So, we have a vector y, and matrix x_i, i=1:10.

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce your plot with

```r
set.seed(1)

xa = runif(20,0,20)
xb = runif(5,50,60)
x  = c(xa,xb)

y  = c(runif(20,25,120),runif(5,30,40))

plot(x,y,xlab="Independent variable",ylab="Response variable",xlim=c(0,60),ylim=c(25,120),pch=16)
```

Comment: Great, the plot is produced exactly! what about the second part, I mean how to make more than one independent variable similar to the one created and stored in a matrix. Let say 10.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty work around for the multidimensional data would be to make a loop that generates `rnorm` values and saves them as column vectors in a dataframe.

Another option is to use the [`MASS` package's `rmvnorm` function.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-53/topics/mvrnorm)

For the outliers, you could generate a bunch of random numbers using `runif(n, min=a, max=b)` using the same loop to dataframe process I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not related to the main idea of the question.

Comment: Then what am I missing?  You want to generate multivariate data with outliers... Well the functions I mentioned let you do that.

Comment: Thanks, what I need is to generate data as in the figure above (specific cluster of outliers), and each time I plot y and any column of x matrix (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5), the same figure will be represented.

Comment: That can still be done with the functions I've listed.  You will need to add the generated multivariate data observations with the generated outliers which can be accomplished with `rbind`.  I'm not sure you could generate multivariate data with outliers baked into it.  Even so, the two step process of combining the observations should create the dataset you want.

Comment: I updated the code but still is not the same as shown in the figure